# Як українською перекласти "streaming" (з виразу "Live-Streaming")

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як українською перекласти *"streaming"* (з виразу *"Live-Streaming"*, яке використовується для позначення телетрансляцій наживо). В укрвікі є стаття про це, але там просто транскрибували англійську назву українською (тобто назвали це [*стрімінґ*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live-Streaming)). Бажано, аби вираз українською використовував українське слово *"струмок"* (що є найбільш коректним перекладом англійського іменника *"stream"*)

P.S. Пам'ятаю, як малим був, то на Українському радіо часто крутили пісню Раїси Кириченко "Я козачка твоя", де у тексті зустрічалось дієслово *"струменіє"* (зокрема у рядку *"Струменіє зоря і за обрій упав // Місяць яблуком червонобокий"*). Так от, це дієслово *струменіє* я не часто зустрічав в українській мові, але, можливо, його можна було б використовувати у значенні англійського *"streaming"*.

Answer (score 11):

**Потокова трансляція, потокове мовлення/відео/мультимедіа**

Вираз *потокова трансляцію* [використовує](http://helpguide.sony.net/cam/1420/v1/uk/cover/level3_27.html), зокрема, компанія Sony. Вживається переважно для трансляцій, що транслюються не в прямому ефірі.

Якщо ж трансляція йде в прямому ефірі, то коректно буде сказати *наживо*, *прямий ефір*, *пряма трансляція* або *потокова трансляція наживо*.

Comment: А як утворити іменник з 'потокова трансляція'? Адже зараз часто вживають' стрімер' в значенні людина що веде трансляцію нвживо

Comment: В такому разі "стрім", проте в конкретно цьому випадку "потокова трансляці" звучить краще. До речі, у слова "стриміти" є інше значення - височіти, здійматись над рівнем, поверхнею чого-небудь.

Comment: А чим погано `стрімер`? Щодня нові слова входять до вжитку з інших мов. Наприклад, [блог](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3) і похідне від нього `блогер`. Якщо не подобається, доведеться увімкнути фантазію і скомпонувати нове слово, скажімо, `потічник` або `струмінник`. Але не певен, що люди сприймуть це.

Answer (score 1):

Такого слова в українській мові немає, але, якщо хочете, можна увімкнути фантазію й самому придумати щось дивакувате. Наприклад:

- *stream* - *стрімóк* (від слова стрімкий, стрімка передача інформації)
- *streaming* - *стрíміння* (наголос на першу `і`)
- *streamer* - *стрімник*

Хоча не певен, що люди це сприймуть.

Щодня до вжитку української мови входять нові слова та вирази, зокрема, і з інших мов. Тому не бачу нічого поганого у термінах *стрім* та *стрімер*. Хіба що ви хочете разюче вирізнитись і показати креативність.

Comment: Знов-таки, не вказано джерела, увесь допис вигляда, як суб'єктивний коментар.

Comment: Звісно, я ж написав: `Такого слова в українській мові немає, але, якщо хочете, можна увімкнути фантазію й самому придумати щось дивакувате.` Як можна дати посилання на неіснуючі слова?

Comment: мені подобається напрямок, але я б почав від слова *струмінь*.