# Як перекласти Live Location?

Tags: переклад, from-english

**Live Location** - це як трансляція вашого розташування в реальному часі, тобто на мапі стрілка рухається за вами. Ось приклади: [Google Maps](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/03/28/location-sharing-going-live-google-maps-everyone/), [Facebook Messenger](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2017/03/introducing-live-location-in-messenger/)

Проблема в тому, що потрібно коротко і ясно.

Ми думали з хлопцями такі варіанти:

- Розташування наживо
- Живе перебування
- динамічне/активне/актуальне/живе/дійсне/реальне/дійове/рухливе/рухоме/змінне/ перебування/розташування
- Рух
- Переміщення
- **Маячок** (який ми вважаємо найкращим варіантом)

Приклади речень:

- You are sharing Live Location in 5 chats.
- Location sharing ended
- Choose for how long people in this chat will see your accuarate location.
- Live location is updated in real time as you move
- [user] started sharing their live location

Comment: Звісно *live* можна перекласти як *активне* чи *динамічне*, але гадаю варто перекласти дослівно, *живе*.

Comment: Також можна використати слово *позиція*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Команда перекладу Telegram вибрала найкращим відповідником саме **Маячок**.

Якщо подивитися на імплементацію цієї функції у Facebook Messenger та Google Maps, його завданням є **відстежувати** (через постійний увімкнений GPS/сервіси локації) **користувача** **та надсилати його розташування** (яке змінюється, адже користувач рухається) іншим користувачам/учасникам чату. Рухаєтеся ви - рухається ваша помітка на мапі.

Тобто, по суті **Live Location** - це свого роду маячок (tracker (відстежувач)), за допомогою якого інші користувачі **бачать ваш рух в реальному часі**.

Чому не інші варіанти?

- Маячок - це коротко і ясно. Його завданням є показувати рух користувача на мапі в реальному часі.
- Поточна точка/місце - це статика. А потрібно точно пояснити, що воно може змінюватися.
- Живе/активне/рухоме/змінне розташування/місцезнаходження і т. д. непогано відображають суть явища, проте дуже ріжуть вуха.

Comment: @Yola Я знаю) Побачив спливну менюшку) Але лише завтра зможу прийняти, це ж обмеження сайту.

Comment: коли переклад з'явиться в офф версії Телеграму?

Comment: @ovnia у нас є бот з локалізацією `@ukrtgbot`, а офіційно локалізація з'явиться (сподіваюся) в наступному оновленні, адже має з'явитися платформа перекладів (судячи з публікацій Дурова у твітері). Раді вас бачити там!)

Answer (score 1):

Live Location — 13 символів

Поточна точка, [поточне місце](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%22) — стїльки ж символів й вживані

---

Означення вельми ясні

> **[Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8)**
>
> [Поточний](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53398/869303.html)
>   Який є, існує, відбувається, має місце тепер, у цей час. Повʼязаний із сучасним моментом.
>
> ---
>
> [Точка](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53410/1000706.html)
>   *переважно* чого або *з означенням* Певне місце, пункт у просторі, на місцевості, у середині або на поверхні чогось. Географічний обʼєкт або предмет на місцевості, що є орієнтиром, позначенням певного місця в просторі або на поверхні землі.
>
> ---
>
> [Місце](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53404/907266.html)
>   *переважно множина* Певна місцевість.

---

**Приклади вживу**

- Ти [перепис](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1119/585)уєте *поточне місце* до 5 бесїд
- *Місце* переписано
- Обрати тривалість відкритостї Твого точного *місця* в цїєї бесїді
- *Поточне місце* змінюється при Твоєму русі
- [користувач] почав перепис свого *поточного місця*

Comment: Нам потрібно, щоб було зрозуміло, що це розташування йде за вами на мапі. Тому ми зупинилися на варіанті "маячок". Дякую за відповідь!

Answer (score 1):

Наскільки я розумію, ваш головний критерій — лаконічність, і бажано, щоб це було одне слово (якщо ні, уточніть у запитанні чи в коментарі до моєї відповіді).

Комерційне програмне забезпечення використовує термін ***місцезнаходження***. Наприклад, допомога Google містить [таку сторінку](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2839911?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=uk):

[image: Google help]

> [**Місцезнахо́дження**](http://sum.in.ua/s/misceznakhodzhennja) — Пункт, місце, де хто-, що-небудь знаходиться.
>
> - *Він один знає **місцезнаходження** дорогоцінної копалини* — Іван Багмут, Опов., 1959, 43
> - *Дельфіни завдяки дуже досконалим локаційним органам можуть визначити не тільки **місцезнаходження** риб, а й їх породу* — Хлібороб України, 1, 1964, 47

Існують також терміни, які менш відповідають вашим потребам, але можуть бути використані за деяких обставин:

- [**Розташува́ння**](http://sum.in.ua/s/roztashuvannja) — це слово має скоріше сенс взаємного розміщення кількох обʼєктів;
- [**Поло́ження**](http://sum.in.ua/s/polozhennja) — особисто мені воно не подобається великою кількістю конотацій, особливо двозначно може сприйматися у сенсі *поза* (положення тіла користувача);

Також, досить часто зустрічається варваризм **локація** (як іменник), хоча словники подають це слово лише як дієслово:

> [**Лока́ція**](http://sum.in.ua/s/lokacija) — **Визначення місцезнаходження** тіла за допомогою локатора або деякими тваринами
>
> - *При ультразвуковій локації серія відбитих сигналів вказує на неоднорідність структури досліджуваних тканин* — Вечірній Київ, 22.VI 1957, 4
> - *На думку спеціалістів, **локація кажанів** у багато разів ефективніша, ніж робота створених для аналогічних цілей технічних пристроїв* — періодична преса

Тобто, у залежності від потреб програмного забезпечення, яке ви розробляєте (наскільки я зрозумів), можна використовувати *місцезнаходження* як іменник і *локація* як дієслово або іменник.

---

Стосовно слова *live*, вважаю, що у нас були гарні відповіді до запитань:

- [Як правильно: в прямому етері, в прямому ефірі чи наживо?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/380/)
- [Як українською перекласти "streaming" (з виразу "Live-Streaming")](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/662/)

Особисто мені подобається варіант *«місцезнаходження наживо»*.